# Python - search dict value from list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that represent specific error codes my code needs to filter out.

```
DMS_WARNING_STOP_REASONS = ["Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR",
                            "Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR", 
                            "Stop Reason STOPPED_DUE_TO_LOW_MEMORY",
                            "Stop Reason STOPPED_DUE_TO_LOW_DISK",
                            "Stop Reason FAILED"
                            ]
```

`StopReason` field from api's response sometimes contains them nested within longer string.

```
dict_response = {'name': 'job_name',
                'Status': 'Stopped',
                'StopReason': "terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2868] [1020101]\n Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL"}
```

I tried using `find` and other methods but don't know how to achieve following behaviour:
Check if any value from `DMS_WARNING_STOP_REASONS` exists/is part of `StopReason` field.

Line that should perform this search is: `if x.get("StopReason") in self.DMS_WARNING_STOP_REASONS`

```
def process_tasks(self, all_tasks: list) -> dict:
    result = {}
    for env in self.envs:
        tasks = [x for x in all_tasks if env in self.__get_task_id(x)]
        
        warnings = [
                {"name": self.__get_task_id(x), "Status": x["Status"],"StopReason": x.get("StopReason", "Stop Reason FAILED")}
                for x in tasks
                if x.get("StopReason") in self.DMS_WARNING_STOP_REASONS
            ]

        working = [...
        ]

        result[env] = {...
        }
    
    return result
```

Comment: `any(reason in dict_response['StopReason'] for reason in DMS_WARNING_STOP_REASONS)`

Comment: Though the above will only work if you remove "Stop Reason " from your DMS_WARNING_STOP_REASONS list (or, if you want to leave this text, reason[12:]).

Comment: getting an error `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` and `KeyError: 'StopReason'`. It seems that `.get("StopReason", "Stop Reason FAILED")` is not recognized by comprehension's later step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-use`.get()` as it modifies the dict in-fly without inserting the key into the dict.

Working solution based of @ILS code:

```
if (any(stop_reason in x.get("StopReason", "Stop Reason FAILED")
```